# Se puede hacer que un operador ternario, ejecute la expresion true, un brake y omita su "else"?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, operador-ternario

Tengo un codigo donde ingreso datos por prompts y se validan, si estan vacios, un alert muestra un mensaje y hace un break, el primer dato obtenido lo valide con un IF y todo bien, pero en el segundo dato se me ocurrio intentarlo con un operador ternario para simplificar y que solo hubiera una linea de codigo y aca es donde aparecen mis preguntas,(si miran el codigo), hay forma de que el operador ternario pueda hacer lo mismo que el IF del primer dato ? osea validar, si es true mostrar una expresion, hacer break y continuar a la otra linea de codigo ?. Por ultimo, no llevo mucho aprendiendo javascript por lo que se me ocurrio esa forma de validar los datos, con un if despues de cada promtp, pero habra una mejor manera de escribir el codigo de las validaciones, otra funcion no se o de esa manera esta bien ? gracias.

```
class libro {

   constructor(titulo, autor, año, genero) {
      this.titulo = titulo
      this.autor = autor
      this.año = año
      this.genero = genero
   }

   informacion() {
      return console.log(`El libro "${this.titulo}" del autor ${this.autor} fue publicado en el año ${this.año} y es de genero ${this.genero}`);
   }
}

function guardarlibro() {

   let libros = [];

   for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

      let titulo = prompt(`Ingresa titulo del libro ${i}`);

      if (titulo == '') {
         alert('No ingresaste ningun dato')
         break
      }

      let autor = prompt(`Ingresa autor del libro ${i}`);

      (autor == '') ? alert('No ingresaste ningun dato'),break;

      let año = prompt(`Ingresa año del libro ${i}`)

      if (año < 4 || isNaN(año) || año == '') {
         alert('No ingresaste ningun dato')
         break
      }

      let genero = prompt(`Ingresa genero del libro ${i}`)
      libros.push(new libro(titulo, autor, año, genero))

   }
   return console.log(libros);
}
guardarlibro()
```

Comment: Reducir código a una línea, haciéndola demasiado compleja no es simplificar ni optimizar como a veces se piensa. Encontrase un "oneliner" complícado lo único que hace es hacer perder el tiempo al sigiente programador que tenga que hacer algún mantenimiento. El operador ternario es útil para expresiones sencillas, pero si va a tener más complejidad es más mantenible el if. Si nuestro código tiene mucha complejidad ciclomática, es preferible refactorizarlo usando más funciones pequeñas a tener que convertir los ifs en ternarios para que ocupe menos líneas.

Comment: @ordago, estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, por esa razón sugiero a @Alex que continue con `if/else`, en mis sesiones he encontrado "onliners" que me han quitado mucho tiempo durante la depuración. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soy neófito en Javascript, sin embargo, con la experiencia que tengo de otros lenguajes, se me ocurre que pudieras hacer una **función de validación** centralizada, algo así:

```
const preguntar = function (msg, typ=undefined) {
    while(true) {
        entry = prompt(msg);
        if((!entry) || (entry.length == 0)) {
            alert('No ingresaste ningun dato');
            continue;
        }
        if (typ == undefined) { return entry; } 
        else if((typ == "num") && !isNaN(entry)) { return parseInt(entry); } 
        else { alert('No ingresaste un numero'); }
    }
}
```

La función puede recibir 1 o 2 parámetros. Si no le mandas el segundo, retorna una cadena no vacía. Si le mandas `'num'` como segundo parámetro, evalúa si la cadena es diferente de `NaN`. De ser así, devuelve un valor entero. Si no se cumple ninguna condición, regresa al inicio del `while`. 
Como podrás ver, esa función es escalable, o sea, la puedes modificar para solicitar más tipos concretos de datos si deseas.

Luego la función principal cambiaría a:

```
function guardarlibro() {
   let libros = [];
   for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      let titulo = preguntar(`Ingresa titulo del libro ${i}`);
      let autor = preguntar(`Ingresa autor del libro ${i}`);
      let año = preguntar(`Ingresa año del libro ${i}`, 'num')
      let genero = preguntar(`Ingresa genero del libro ${i}`)
      libros.push(new libro(titulo, autor, año, genero))
   }
   return console.log(libros);
}
```

Sobre el *operador ternario*, se debe emplear cuando hay una sola instrucción por evaluación. Si se requieren más instrucciones en una misma evaluación sea verdadera o falsa, usar `if` normal.

Comment: Para ser neófito, lo explicaste muy bien. +1

Answer (score 2):

Hay un error mínimo en la sintáxis del ejemplo proporcionado, pero es irrelevante, pues aunque se corrigiera, no se puede usar un `break` dentro de un operador ternario:

```
/*aún corrigiendo el error de sintáxis, se tendría el mensaje de error*/
//(autor == '') ? alert('No ingresaste ningun dato'),break;
(autor == '') ? alert('No ingresaste ningun dato') : break;
```

Suponiendo que se corrige este error, JS regresaría un mensaje como este:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'break'

El operador condicional ternario es un operador que combina varias **Expressions**(indicaciones escritas) en una Expresión más grande:

> condition ? expression1 : expression2

Por otro lado,  `break` es un **Statement** (declaración descriptiva para controlar flujo) y no una Expresión, por lo que no se puede usar dentro de una expresión condicional ternaria.

Las validaciones que estás haciendo con `if/else` van bien, pues son **inteligibles**, yo seguiría usándolas de ser necesario, ya que como lo mencionas, estas iniciando tus estudios de JS.